# Why do I get error "ArgumentException was thrown on "ViewModelLocator": Cannot create an instance of "ViewModelLocator"

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm-light

I have narrowed down to a simple method where I am attempting to fill an Observable collection from an entity model. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.

Note: this appears to be a designer error. I can build and run the program...so it appears.

```
    private ObservableCollection<LessonGroup> lessonGroups;
    public ObservableCollection<LessonGroup> LessonGroups
    {
        get { return LessonGroups; }
        set { lessonGroups = value; RaisePropertyChanged("LessonGroups"); }
    }


    private void GetLessonGroups()
    {
        //this using statement causes ArgumentException
        using (MyEntities ae = new MyEntities())
        {
            foreach (LessonGroup lg in ae.LessonGroups)
            {
                LessonGroups.Add(lg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception is as follows:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
   at IMPACT.ARCTrainer.Model.ARCTrainerEntities..ctor() in C:\Users\Leland\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ARCTrainer\Model\ARCTrainer.Designer.cs:line 56
   at IMPACT.ARCTrainer.ViewModel.LessonsViewModel.GetLessonGroups() in C:\Users\Leland\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ARCTrainer\ViewModel\LessonsViewModel.cs:line 171
   at IMPACT.ARCTrainer.ViewModel.LessonsViewModel..ctor(ViewModelLocator viewModelLocator) in C:\Users\Leland\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ARCTrainer\ViewModel\LessonsViewModel.cs:line 37
   at IMPACT.ARCTrainer.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator..ctor() in C:\Users\Leland\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ARCTrainer\ViewModel\ViewModelLocator.cs:line 46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetLessonGroups seems to be called within the constructor of your class LessonsViewModel.

This method make a call to MyEntities and it looks like this Entity Framework context is not is the same project that the GUI project.

To resolve your issue, the best way you have is to check wether you are in Design mode or not. If you are using MVVM Light, you can check the IsInDesignMode property (and thus, call the GetLessonGroups method only if the property is false).

Comment: Checking IsInDesignMode was a good idea and helped me get rid of the design time error. I am still curious what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You called an Entity Framework DataContext within a constructor: this will connect to your database when a designer is opened so i would suggest you to avoid this.